# Mat Table getting multiple values of each row

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat table connected thru firestore via an observable as its datasource.

```
  detailstoPay: unpaidModel;

 ngOnInit(): void {

    this.customerService.getUnpaid().subscribe(unpaidObs => {
      this.unpaidList = unpaidObs;
      this.dataUnpaidSource = new MatTableDataSource(unpaidObs)
    });   
  }
```

[image]

If I click one individually, I can able to get the data and process it because I've added a click function below my Mat Table

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedUnpaidColumns;"
(click)="loadToPayment(row)"></tr>
```

component.ts

```
  loadToPayment(rows:unpaidModel) {
    console.log(rows)
    this.detailstoPay = rows;
  }
```

if I console log, I can see the whole information about that account.

However, I want to ask for help on what I can do, if I want to click up to three rows and load it all at the same, like an add to cart feature.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you could add multi-select checkmark to each row. After selecting desired rows you would hit a button (much like the one you have for each row at the moment) that would processAllRows();

How to add checkbox for multi select example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-selection

1. Upon checking/unchecking an row add it to array of checkedRows.

```html
      <mat-checkbox
          class="example-margin"
          (change)=addOrRemoveRow($event)>
        I'm a checkbox
      </mat-checkbox>
```

```js
checkedRows: any = [];

addOrRemoveRow(event: any) {
if (!checkedRows.includes(event.value)) {
   this.checkedRows.push(event.value
   } else {
    this.checkedRows.splice(this.checkedRows.indexOf(event.value), 1)
   }
}
```

2. processAllRows() would process rows one by one whilst removing them from the array checkedRows.

```js
processAllRows() {
for (let row of selectedRows) {
    loadToPayment(selectedRows.pop());
  }
}
```

You could then afterwards remove the row or remove the checkmark - whatever should happen next.

Comment: Got it working~ thank you again for the time and help @joosep :D

Comment: If you don't mind for another question, I was able to get the values of each row and put them into an array. may I know how to get the specific value on the index on each row from the array? like for example I would like just to get all payments of each row in the array. Thank you

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you correctly, but the data you see on your table is coming from `unpaidObs`. Most likely data on table is in same order as data in `unpaidObs`. So `unpaidObs[0] == table positsion 1`. But I guess it would be safer to iterate over this.dataUnpaidSource (thats the table data) and find object where your `findValue == object.value`, then ask the index of that object.